# How to replace ' / ' with '-' inside ObservableArray ? Knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Well i am trying to pass an observable array via ajax call to my controller but i get every value there except date . i get something like '01-01-01' etc .

I found the issue but unable to fix that as i dont know how to replace `/` with `-` .

My ObservableArray have around 10 list items each list item holds a many properties out of those `startDate` holds the date like `("23/10/2014")` . i just need something like `("23-10-2014")` .

Tought of posting my function's and more i hope thats not required in this case i believe .

**Let me explain with bit of code and sample data :**

```
function myarray()
{
var self=this;
self.startDate=ko.observable("");
self.name=ko.observable("");
self.place=ko.observable("");
}
```

**MyObservableArray :**

```
self.Main= ko.observableArray();
```

In between i do some stuff to load Data into `self.Main` and i am sending self.Main to controller having data like below :

```
self.Main[0] holds : 

startDate() -->gives you  "23/10/2014" //individual observables inside onservable array
name() --> "jhon"
place()--> "croatia"
```

Likely

```
self.Main[9] holds :
startDate() --> "29/05/2012" 
    name() --> "pop"
    place()--> "usa"
```

I am trying like i want to alter the self.Main() and replace the startDate and use the same self.Main to send to my controller . Once after replacing in `self.Main` when i check date the `/` should be replaced with `-` .

**Possible solution :** i can use a different observable array and push all the VM's of `Main` into it but i am trying to do on `self.Main` without using other .

If someone can show some light it is much appreciated .

Comment: what was the problem, what did you try?

Comment: @Mritunjay well i am not familiar with knockout as i just knew `replacewith` in jquery which wont be helpful in my case .

Comment: have you tried sending date like this "23-10-2014"?

Comment: Why can't you try simple JS I've added in answer.

Comment: `Akhlesh` yes i am trying so . i have no clue how to alter observable inside observableArray .

Answer (score 1):

What I got that you are facing problem in escaping `/` in replace.

Try this

```
"(23/10/2014)".replace(/\//g,"-") //returns "(23-10-2014)"
```

I tried something for you using simple JS

```
var arr = [{date:"(23/10/2014)"},{date:"(23/10/2014)"},{date:"(23/10/2014)"},{date:"(23/10/2014)"}];

arr.forEach(function(obj){obj.date = obj.date.replace(/\//g,"-")});

console.log(arr) //will print date field as "(23-10-2014)" for all objects.
```

Comment: yes point was that but how to do replacing in each observable inside observableArray is the main thing

Comment: @supercool I'm not familiar with knockout, can't you use array functions like  `each`.

Comment: You would do a for each loop. For each x as array name and place the replace js inside the loop.

Comment: i worked with `ko.utils.arrayForEach` let me check and let you know

Comment: This solution would get the values replaced, but it's only part of the solution, considering that he's using knockout.js.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add a `computed` value that returns the array with the right values.

```
self.Main = ko.observableArray([...values here...]);

self.MainComputed = ko.computed(function() { 
  var computedArray = [];

  self.Main().forEach(function(item) {
    var newItem = myarray(); //Create a new item.
    newItem.name(item.name());
    newItem.place(item.place());
    newItem.startDate(item.startDate().replace(/\//g,"-"));
    computedArray.push(newItem);
  });

  return computedArray;
});
```

Then use the computed value in the places where you need the values with `-`.

---

I can think of two other ways to solve your issue, when taken into account that you want to use `self.Main`:

1. Replace the `/` with `-` before setting `startDate` on your item.
2. Change `startDate` to a computed value while storing the original value in another variable.

The first solution should be pretty straight forward (provided that it is a valid solution).

The second solution would look something like this:

```
function myarray()
{
  var self=this;
  self.originalStartDate = ko.observable("");
  self.name = ko.observable("");
  self.place = ko.observable("");

  self.startDate = ko.computed(function() {
    if(self.originalStartDate()) {
      //We can only replace if the value is set.
      return self.originalStartDate().replace(/\//g,"-");
    }
    else {
      //If replace was not possible, we return the value as is.
      return self.originalStartDate();
    }
  });
}
```

Now when you set the values you do something like:

```
var item = myarray();
item.originalStartDate = "01/01/2014";
```

Then when you get the value of `startDate` you would get `"01-01-2014"`.

Comment: updated my code may be that clears something :) i like computed stuff .

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your added code. I still believe that using a `computed` is the way to go. That way your data will always be in sync.

Comment: I added a few other suggestions, that you could consider as a solution.

Comment: well actually i keep on trying to alter `self.Main` instead of doing  on initial `Get` beoz on first load i am using computed to change my format from 12-12-2012 to 12/12/2012 . later i have to convert back but its a tricky scenario now right .

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Knockout.js but you can do this with a Javascript replace:

```
var str = [your array value] ;
var res = str.replace("/", "-");
```

For more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace